# Escaped url when setting a css variable with js

Tags: javascript, html, css

im trying to set a css custom property with js. The name of the property should be "--path" and the value should be "url(test.png)".

My code looks like this:

`window.document.body.style.setProperty("--path", "url(test.png)");`

My problem is that now the value of --path is `"url(test\.png)"`. How can i prevent the escaping of this dot?

Comment: Using `'test.png'` in single quotes will do the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add quotes to the path:

```js
window.document.body.style.setProperty("--path", "url('test.png')");
```